# Watched tags highlighting lost

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-watching

On both Chrome Version 91.0.4472.77 and Safari Version 14.1.1 running on MacOS 10.15.7, I've lost the color-highlighting of front-page Top Questions in my Watched Tags list. Is this just my problem, or did something change at StackExchange?

Comment: I can confirm that on Chromium 91.0.4472.77 (Official Build) Arch Linux (64-bit) the highlighting on watched tags (on the front page) is missing. Similarly on math.SE the colour highlighting is missing.

Comment: Same problem with Firefox 68esr.

Comment: Same bug on SO and MO Meta, but not on SO Meta.

Comment: [meta.se]: [Ignored and watched tags seem broken](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/366321)

Comment: @MartinSleziak: Do you know: Is there some action we should take in order to restore highlighting? I gather from your link that it has been resolved in some (perhaps limited) sense.

Comment: This seems to be the latest information: [Marc Gravell](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/366345/228808).

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke I have posted a screenshot showing what I see [in the MathOverflow charoom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9369/conversation/highlighting-for-watched-tags). (Maybe also somebody else will do so either here or in chat.)

Comment: The highlighting is still broken for me. Chrome 91.0.4472.101.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins: Ditto for me---Still broken.

Comment: @MartinSleziak: Did you take any action to achieve that screenshot? What browser are you using?

Comment: It seems to me that it's fixed now.